# Deploy URL Deprecated. How do I configure the alternative?

Tags: angular, angular-config

In Angular 13 when I build my application, I recieve the following warning:

`Option "deployUrl" is deprecated: Use "baseHref" option, "APP_BASE_HREF" DI token or a combination of both instead. For more information, see https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-deploy-url.`

I have read the documentation page but I am struggling to wrap my head around it.

This occurs because in my `angular.json` I have multiple builds, but this only applies to the `production` configuration:

```
...
    deployURL: "https://cdn.lol.com/prod/app"
...
```

**What would I need to do to achieve the same outcome as deployURL?**

I considered creating an `environment.production.ts` file with a `baseHref` property and then I could use a provider in my app module. (See [APP_BASE_HREF Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF)) but assuming I do that, I don't really understand where I would use the Token correctly.  I also don't really understand what my new relationship would be with assets.

As far as I understand, `deployURL` was specifically for routes, whereas `baseHref` effects both routes and assets (or can?).  This seems to open a can of worms.

I would appreciate any insight!

Thanks.

Comment: To get the same outcome of deployUrl you might use a custom-webpack builder for your app and configure your webpack.config.js publicPath. Which will result the same as deployUrl.

Comment: @MehyarSawas Thanks for the suggestion, although I am familar with Webpack, I don't fancy digging that deep or maintaining it.  The app is from version 4 and has passed all versions through to 13, so if I had to consider maintaining a custom webpack config through all of this time, i'd be probably grey haired! :)!

Comment: @user1059939 have you been able to fix this issue?

Comment: @TristanVanPoucke Nope  We actually decided to host assets externally, not for this particular reason but it made the original question obsolete.  Good luck.

Comment: Okay tnx, I'll guess I will log an issue with angular, cause none of the alternatives proposed offer a solution for this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app.module.ts, you can use it like below given SS to update the deploy url.

[image]